# Image Gallery permission setting changes after updating to minimum SDK 33 android 13

Tags: ionic-framework, sdk, android-13

I am having compatibility issues for devices running on android 13 after updating the minimum target sdk to 33.

Image Gallery Issue
"Error 20" whenever I try to upload an image from the device image gallery which prevents me from opening the image gallery.

**Attempted Solution**

Updated android manifest by adding the new set of permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
```

Old set of permissions still remain for backwards compatibility with older versions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**CameraLauncher.java ( Commented permission denied code )**

```
public void onRequestPermissionResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                      int[] grantResults) throws JSONException {
    for (int r : grantResults) {
        // if (r == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        //     this.callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, PERMISSION_DENIED_ERROR));
        //     return;
        // }
    }
    switch (requestCode) {
        case TAKE_PIC_SEC:
            takePicture(this.destType, this.encodingType);
            break;
        case SAVE_TO_ALBUM_SEC:
            this.getImage(this.srcType, this.destType, this.encodingType);
            break;
    }
}
```

**Project Specification**

1. Ionic V3
2. Cordova